# cant init db for airflow docker-compose permission denied

Tags: airflow

I am trying to run the docker-compose file from the main airflow website and when I try to do `docker-compose up airflow-init` it fails and gives me:

```
airflow-init_1       |     with open(AIRFLOW_CONFIG, 'w') as file:
airflow-init_1       | PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg'
```

Most of the services show this same error, such as the `flower_1, airflow-webserver_1, airflow-worker_1 and airflow-scheduler_1`. It reaches the maximum 20 retires and gives up.

I tried to do `chmod -R 777` on the directory where the `airflow.cfg` lives but same error comes up. In the docker-compose.yml file I have:

```
volumes:
  - ./airflow.cfg:/opt/airflow/airflow.cfg
```

I tried without mounting the `airflow.cfg` file but now I get this message:

```
 ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/airflow/logs/scheduler'
```

I checked the directory permissions and it looks like this: `drwxrwxrwx`.

I'm not sure what else to try. I'm running on RHEL VM. Appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @spencer-trinh, I am facing the same issue now out of a sudden. Weirdest thing is, I haven't even mounted `airflow.cfg`. Were you able to solve this? How?

Answer (score 1):

I added `:z` to the end of the mount, like:

```
volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags:z
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs:z
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins:z
```

as shown in this [github thread](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/23589), and it magically works. I wasn't sure what the `:z` does until I found this other [SO post](http://The%20z%20option%20indicates%20that%20the%20bind%20mount%20content%20is%20shared%20among%20multiple%20containers) that explains what it means.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.env` file that is located at the same level as the docker-compose file, you should have these variables declared:

```
AIRFLOW_UID=1000
AIRFLOW_GID=0`
```

The number of each variable has to correspond to the *user_id* and *group_id* of your OS from which you are running Airflow. In the terminal run this:

`echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0"`

Then update the values in the `.env` file.

Also, you should check that every folder and file in the root Airflow folder, has the same user as owner, if not change it by running `chown -r your_user:your_group`.

Source [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#initializing-environment). Let me know if that worked for you

Comment: hi @NicoE, thanks for the suggestion. I did follow those steps from the website. So, I do have the `.env` that has the contents of `AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)\nAIRFLOW_GID=0`. I also tried the `chown -r $(whoami):$(id -g)` but I am still encountering the same error.